# would living in a digital world would be considered a death sentence in the real world?

Tags: computers, science-in-society

In a world similar to ours, a scientist discovered a way to transplant a soul or what makes a person a person without a body into a particular instance in a computer. In the scientist excitement, he/she does a test on him/herself. Now, there is no api for the soul instance to function with the computer because this is the first test of its kind. The only thing that scientist knows is that the computer that he/she is going can hold the scientist's soul. Would the scientist be theoretically killed or would be able to live in the computer and be able to communicate with other technologies that computer is connected to with any prior coding of what the instance of the soul can do once in the computer?

**What I am asking**

If someone was able to upload themselves into a computer that only had a program to sustain the essence of a human's soul or what make that person unique, would it be considered a suicide or would the person, once inside the computer be able to manipulate the computer in such a way that the person can literally take over the computer and possibility other computers without any prior coding in the program to make that person do so?

Comment: Sounds like [TRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron) or [SouthPark's version of FaceBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Have_0_Friends)

Comment: It would all depend upon how the computer is programmed initially and on how much you can manipulate a computer if you put your soul in it. It would also depend on if you can put your soul back in its body.

Comment: It would be a one and done deal

Comment: This is a major open question in philosophy.  It can only be answered by truly knowing what it means to be a Self, and what it means to have a soul.  Many philosophers have come up with answers for this in both directions.  It may be that he is living, it may be that he is dead.  It may be that that question is more complicated than a simple yes or no answer will suffice for.

Comment: @FrancoPettigrosso Check out the Ghost In The Shell franchise. What you call "soul" is what is the titular "ghost" in the GITS universe.

Comment: Are you talking about something other than mind uploading? Is this science based of fantasy? What is a soul? This can't be answered as asked.

Comment: Since the question is now well worded, I think it deserves to be un-holded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is your use of the word soul. Nobody knows what it means to exist as a soul.

We know what it means to exist as a body. That would certainly be ending.

We also know what it means to exist as a mind. "I think therefore I am." Therefore if I am thinking I am.

Can the scientist think while inside the machine? If not it would be meaningless to say he or she was in there. Are the components of the computer available for use? E.G. when transcoding the consciousness were provisions made so the consciousness could actively control the machinery of the computer? Can the consciousness see and hear and communicate, travel to other computers (if not it's locked into a perpetual hell of thinking but no outside stimulus. Given that computers are super fast the perceived time would greatly exceed real time)? You might be tempted to say they can't move around, but remember that copying digital data is trivial --again think of it as a mind transcoded to a computer rather than a soul.

I think we're assuming that no provision has been made for a simulated life, so you've got whatever already exists on computers and that's it. There's no sensation of body, no simulation of emotion (though these are certainly possible they'd have to be set up ahead of time.) Basically all you get is interacting with the computer in all the ways that have already been set up. Maybe online gaming would still work about the same way, but it wouldn't be immersive. You'd simply see the game in third person just like a regular user.

Would existing without a body be good or bad? Emotions are probably almost entirely chemically derived (again, you might be able to fake emotions inside a computer, but this alone could be the work of a lifetime of hardware and system design) so you might end up with a pure reasoning creature with memory of emotion but no real way to feel anymore. You might be terrified by the choices made out of pure reason.

The person would be incapable of suffering though. The worst it could get would be the abstract thought. This sucks. And maybe the decision that existence has nothing to recommend it over not existence at which point the computer person quietly executed the command

```
rm -rf /
```

Now here's a troubling thought. What if the electronic person took it a step further and decided to end all life entirely since there was nothing logical to recommend it over non existence.

Comment: In Greg Egan's *Permutation City* it is a legal requirement that a simulated person is given a simulated off switch to terminate the simulation should he/she/it choose. This law is of course broken ....

Comment: once you think about it... psych would probably  deteriorate after a couple seconds since computer time is much faster than "Human" time. to explain myself,a computer does more in a second than a human. So In my theory, the computer would be able to just process the thoughts allot faster and maybe, depending on the determination of the person being trapped in the computer, can probably make every thought possible then just decide to kill him/herself because of boredom.

Comment: I disagree that an electronic personality's perception of time would necessarily compressed due to the speed of computer processors. I suspect that consciousness is an abstraction layer atop a lot of different subprocesses. Our brains are massively parallel neural networks. It's difficult to know how that would translate into a machine, but I suspect that the first electronic minds will not have a substantially different perception of time (though they may grow to this level since they can scale up and out)